# Occasionally write all data stored on ramdisk to SD card

Tags: sd-card

I'm using tmpfs on my SD card for working with I/O intensive programs. 
From time to time (let's say once a day) I want that all data should write to SD card to be on the safe side in case of power failure (in backuped folder). 
Any idea how to do it?

Comment: `cron` would be my go to for such a task

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I understand that part of creating a recurring task. But I don't know how to clear the ramdisk.

Comment: Not sure you can directly do this, as it's intended to be temporary storage. You could try the usual disk imaging tools (`dd` or `partimage`) but I'm not sure that's what you want. A more elegant way might be to investigate having a partition on the SD card and then using a union mount (e.g. "OverlayFS" or "aufs") to put the tmpfs over it that you can then sync to the actual SD card once in while?

Comment: Does exists "unmount" and then "mount" again for tmpfs mounted in fstab? This would maybe be a solution.

Answer (score 2):

To backup all data from the temp directory just create a daily cron job with a tar backup job. For example this tar would do it, assuming it is executed as root:

```
rpi ~# /bin/tar -czf /backupdir/backup-from-tmpdir.tar.gz -V "daily backup from tmpfs" -C /tmpdir/ ./
```

Comment: Would `dd` work also?

Comment: @Seamus I have just no idea. With `dd` you need a device file, something like `/dev/tmpfs` but that doesn't exist. Just the same with `/proc` and other virtual file systems. Maybe there is a way to use a loop device?